# Preparing XSD of a complex xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xsd

Thank you all for suggesting things and helping whenever in need.

Yesterday I was trying to develop and web app in asp.net 4.0 where I needed to parse the data from xml and save it in database. But before that I will also have to validate it.

I tried using .net provided tool xsd.exe to generate the schema file, but I dont know how will it know to mark which nodes or attributes are compulsory?

Like in my xml below items are mandatory

```
Root node <Market> 
<Login> and its sub element
<ProductType> and its <ProductTypeID/>
The attribute DML is mandatory but should have only 3 values NONE, PUT or MODIFY
<ProductType> may or may not have <ProductItem>
If <ProductItem> is present then it should have <ProductItemID>
<ProductItem> may or may not have <Brand>
If <Brand> is present then it should have <BrandID>
```

Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Market>
    <Login>
        <LoginId />
        <Password />        
    </Login>

    <ProductType DML="NONE">
        <ProductTypeID/>
        <Name/>
        <Detail/>       

        <ProductItem DML="PUT">
            <ProductItemID/>
            <Name/>
            <Detail/>

            <Brand DML="PUT">
                <BrandID/>
                <Name/>
                <Detail/>
            </Brand>

            <Brand DML="MODIFY">
                <BrandID/>
                <Name/>
                <Detail/>
            </Brand>
        </ProductItem>

        <ProductItem DML="MODIFY">
            <ProductItemID/>
            <Name/>
            <Detail/>
        </ProductItem>        
    </ProductType>
</Market>
```

How and where should I specify all the mandatory and optional parameters, so that my xsd is generated as per the requirement.

Thanks,

M.

Answer (score 0):

xsd.exe can only try to infer, which elements/attributes are in you xml, but it cannot find out which information is mandatory. But this is a good startingpoint.

use a [graphical XML_Schema_Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_Editor) to edit the genrated xsd to mark your mandatory fields. That is much easier than learning the xsd-language

Comment: oh, that means I will have to specifically edit the xsd which is generated by xsd.exe, Doesnt vs2010 provides any tool which makes this easy?

Comment: you can use vs2010 to edit the xsd but i think that it converts attributes like "DML" in you example into elements after changes. vs2003 xsd editor does not do this. vs xsd editor focusses on typed datasets. In Microsofts dataset implementation it doesnt matter wether DML is an attribute or an element when reading the xml.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think XSD support nested XML. I would try to load the XML into an `XmlDocument` and check mandatory fields manually.